# pandas groupby calculating and index issues

Tags: python, pandas

there are 720 + thousands rows in a csv.

columns in csv is 'Department', 'Product', 'Checkout', 'Date','Time','Basket','Total'

1. i wanna group by basket and datetime( i will combine it) and get the sum of checkout

it works but problem is i need to wait for ages

2.
i tried to set Basket and datetime as index
i did this through read_csv function, merge date and time into datetime, and set basket and datetime as the index

but i cant group them after that. it said , key error

Comment: You can call `sum` on the df after calling `set_index` but you then need to define if you want to `sum` on the 1st or 2nd level of your index so `df['Checkout'].sum(level='basket')` or `df['Checkout'].sum(level='datetime')` or similar

Comment: it works~. but another prob. speed is so shitty. any suggestion?

Comment: Are your datetimes string or real datetime dtype? Also is Basket string or numeric? It maybe quicker if the datetime is real datetime dtype and you replace Basket with some integer ID

Comment: Can you show a little bit of the data (ie `df.head()`)
Also can you qualify `wait for ages` ? Minutes ? Half an hour ?

Comment: haha. it works. thanks bro. all of you